# Match a string using grep

Tags: regex, unix, grep, pattern-matching

I want to match the below string using a regular expression in grep command.

File name is `test.txt`,

```
Unknown Unknown

Jessica Patiño

Althea Dubravsky 45622

Monique Outlaw 49473

April Zwearcan 45758

Tania Horne 45467
```

I want to match the lines containing special characters alone from the above list of lines; the line which I exactly need is 'Jessica Patiño', which contains a non-ASCII character.

I used,

```
grep '[^0-9a-zA-Z]' test.txt
```

But it returns all lines.

Comment: All those lines have `\s` (space) in them.

Comment: Try `grep '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]' test.txt`.

Comment: Do any names have apostrophes?  D'Arcy, O'Malley, O'Keefe, etc may or may not have "special" characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command should return the lines you want:

```
grep -v '^[0-9a-zA-Z ]*$' test.txt
```

### Explanation

- `[0-9a-zA-Z ]` matches a space or any alphanumeric character.
- Adding the asterisk matches any string containing only these characters.
- Prepending the pattern with `^` and appending it with `$` *anchors* the string to the beginning and end of line so that the pattern matches only the lines which contain *only* the desired characters.
- Finally, the `-v` or `--invert-match` option to grep inverts the sense of matching, i.e., select non-matching lines.

Answer (score 1):

The provided answers should work for the example text given. However, you're likely to come across people with hyphens or apostrophes in their names, etc. To search for all non-ASCII characters, this should do the trick:

```
grep -P "[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]" test.txt
```

-P enables "Perl" mode and allows use of character code searches. \x00-\x1F are control characters, and \x7F-\xFF is everything above 126.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
grep [^0-9a-zA-Z\s]+ test.txt
```

[live example](https://regex101.com/r/aI0bN4/6)

Or, even better:

```
 grep -i "[^\da-z\s]" test.txt
```

Comment: 1) I recommend quoting your regex. `grep` is a shell command, and most shells will consider square brackets "special".  2) If you're going to use a `+`, you'll need `egrep` or `grep -E` to denote an Extended Regular Expression (ERE).  And 3), if you're just looking for any character that does not match the range in square brackets, there's no point in `+`. A single character match is enough to qualify a line for printing. Aside from these issues, I think this is the superior solution, as it doesn't require processing of every character on each line.